# How to get form input values?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, variables

Above code is my html form. I want to use input text value with Variables

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
 <input class="form-control" name="old_thumb" id="disabledInput" type="text" value="{$gelen_goster[1]}" disabled>
<br />
<input type="file" name="thumb">
<br />
<input type="submit' value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

this is my php code

```
if($_FILES['thumb']['error']==0){
        $thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'], "../demo/clients/" . $_FILES['thumb']['name']);
        }
    if (empty($_FILES['thumb']['name'])) {
        $thumb = $_POST['old_thumb']; //***HOW CAN USE FORM'S INPUT VALUE ?***
        }
```

Comment: $_POST is your target. what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The disabled field isn't sent. You can still display the value and use a hidden field to send it. Like this

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
 <input class="form-control"  id="disabledInput" type="text" value="{$gelen_goster[1]}" disabled>

<input class="form-control" name="old_thumb" type="hidden" value="{$gelen_goster[1]}">

<br />
<input type="file" name="thumb">
<br />
<input type="submit' value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the field to readonly. Disabled fields don't get submitted, readonly do.

```
<input class="form-control" name="old_thumb" id="disabledInput" type="text" value="{$gelen_goster[1]}" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

READONLY and DISABLED both remove the functionality of the input field, but to different degrees.

READONLY locks the field: the user cannot change the value.

DISABLED does the same thing but takes it further: the user cannot use the field in any way, not to highlight the text for copying, not to select the check-box, not to submit the form. In fact, a disabled field is not even sent if the form is submitted.

So if you want to display input field but does not want users to edit this then Use `READONLY`

```
 <input class="form-control" name="old_thumb" id="disabledInput" type="text" value="{$gelen_goster[1]}" readonly>
```

If using Hidden then input field will not be visible but it will get posted on form submission.